# How to run ansible-galaxy command on kickstart %post script

Tags: linux, installation, ansible

Running a Rocky Linux 8 install trying %post script to run ansible-galaxy but find it hard as it will drop this error:

`/mnt/sysimage/bin/ansible-galaxy: /usr/bin/python3.9: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` 
Any solution for this?

On my package part have added python3 and this is appearing under

`/mnt/sysimage/bin/python3.9`

my guess for this error is that ansible-galaxy is looking for python and not finding it under /usr/bin

Don’t really know best solution for this. Came up with link the one from /mnt to /usr and solve this with by changing the interpreter… So i have now this:

`%post --nochroot --interpreter=/mnt/sysimage/bin/python3.9 --log=/root/ansible-post.log` 
But it comes out now with another error:

`/mnt/sysimage/bin/python3.9 error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: From the `ansible` tag description: On-topic questions are concerned with the use of the tool itself. Installing Ansible and prerequisites, connection issues, ... are off-topic.